# how to accesse ethereum?

Tags: wallets

so this is probebly a wierd one. but my father recently passed away due to cancer. and well he has this ethereum wallet with i think 21 eth or something like that. which i am now trying to help my mother get access to. how do i do? he was useing Bit-trading online. and i got the wallets code. but we dont understand who it works nor what to do.  thank you for any tips or help that you have.

Comment: sorry for any typos im swedish and english is not my strongest side

Comment: Don’t share that wallet code to anyone, don’t show it or share it with anyone online is asking. They will steal ur money and run away

Comment: Try to find someone understand and use ethereum and if he gonna help you do it,  then better personally and maybe write an agreement and give him 1 ether for it

Answer (score 4):

I'm sorry to hear about your father.

First, you should be in fine shape if you have access to the wallet, but a word of caution. Ethereum was borne out of a desire to evict all-powerful intermediaries from certain kinds of financial relationships. The solution is an adversarial environment in which it is assumed that everyone wants to steal everyone else's money. The system protects itself from bad actors in a Darwinian-like fashion but a side-effect is that bad actors are all over the place and many seem to think that ethical controls just don't apply. I would urge extreme caution with online "helpers" who might just be hoping you will reveal the "secret" that lets them take the money.

Others might chime in with technical advice. It might be a little "much" and I don't think anyone should learn Ethereum with $40K at stake. It's going to be a multi-step process and it might not be "fun." As well as confirming your control of the funds, you have to decide what to do with them. Keep them in Ethereum? Convert to Euros? Something else?

Rather than embarking on a technical adventure, I might suggest you find a local meet-up where you might meet a trustworthy and experienced mentor who can possibly help you out, in person, and explain what's going on. That's the advice I would give a family member in a similar situation.

Hope it helps.

Comment: okey i will see if there is anyone local i can get help from thank you

Comment: A group organizer would possibly be a good place to start. I'd look for someone with a reputation so there would be accountability as well as a social cost if something went sideways. It wouldn't be unreasonable to offer a small fee for the help which possibly strengthens your legal position. A dollar is a contract, as they say.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to hear about your father.

This resource is a good place to start. It links to additional resource on how to access your funds & how to keep them safe: https://ethereum.org/en/wallets/